# Ruby - how to pull out that is betweet two "points"?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, substring

I have a text like this:

```
...
Sentence one. hsjdhsd jghdsjghjdskhgjksdh kjghdsjkg

sdgsdg
dgds
hfdhdf
h
fdh
dfh Sentence two. gdjshagjhsdga sdgjhsdkjgh adskjghdsa
gs a
gfdgfdhfdhh
...
```

And I would need to pull from this paragraph the text that is between strings (actually it's a sentence) **Sentence one.** and **Sentence two.**.

Could you help me guys, please, how to pull it?

Thanks

Comment: You didn't include what you have so far?

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to differentiate an arbitrary real sentence verses gibberish with a reasonable regular expression. Some kind of simple parser is probably going to be your best bet.

Comment: `/Sentence one(.*?)Sentence two/m`

will work, but only if `Sentence one` and `Sentence two` are exact and not nested.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at what you have, the start and end of your sentence are a capital letter and a period, respectively.  You can construct a regular expression that pulls out the text between a capital letter and the first period that comes after.

But this may be a contrived example; it looks like you may have types random keys in the middle of the keyboard, so this may not be the characteristics of your actual gibberish.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this`([A-Z]{1}.*\.)`?

Answer (score 0):

### Use a Conditional Flip-Flop Expression

Given your corpus as defined above:

```
ruby -ne 'puts $_ if /Sentence/ ... /Sentence/' /tmp/corpus
```

will output:

```
Sentence one. hsjdhsd jghdsjghjdskhgjksdh kjghdsjkg

sdgsdg
dgds
hfdhdf
h
fdh
dfh Sentence two. gdjshagjhsdga sdgjhsdkjgh adskjghdsa
```